# Why does my makefile call gcc although I set CC=g++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, g++

I have a small code that compiles with `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Og -g -o main *.cc` perfectly. Now I want tor have a makefile and so far I got this:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -Og -g
DEPS = random_tools.h
OBJ = main.o random_tools.o

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

main: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

However, when I run `make` it crashes, telling me

```
g++    -c -o main.o main.cc
g++    -c -o random_tools.o random_tools.cc
gcc -Wall -o main main.o random_tools.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cc:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(int)'
main.cc:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cc:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cc:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cc:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:10: main] Error 1
```

What I really don't get is why it uses `gcc` instead of `g++` - I am telling it to use `g++`. Can somebody shed light on what happens here and how I can make `make` do what I say? Thanks.

Comment: Because you explicitely use it in the linker command: `gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^`?

Comment: Note that `CC` is conventionally supposed to be a C compiler, not C++ compiler. The normal variables for the C++ compiler is `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: It's a bad idea to take make variables commonly associated with C and use them for C++. It is also a bad idea to give your C++ source files a suffix of .c.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for that hint. Is it a naming convention only or does it also trigger different behaviour?

Comment: It's a naming convention used by the default rules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This rule

```
main: $(OBJ)
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

has "gcc" hardwired into it.  Change that to `$(CC)` and it will behave as you expect.

That said, it would be better all around to write this Makefile like this:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++17 -Og -g
DEPS = random_tools.h
OBJ = main.o random_tools.o

# Default goal
main: $(OBJ)
    $(LINK.cc) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

# Header dependencies
$(OBJ): $(DEPS)
```

This uses the built-in Make conventions, so it will be much easier to expand later.  (I do not have space to explain all the built-in Make conventions here.  I recommend you read the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) cover to cover.)

(Note that this will *not* do what you expect if you actually named your source files `main.c` and `random_tools.c` rather than `main.cc` and `random_tools.cc`.  But you should use `.cc` for C++ source files anyway.)

Comment: You should take `LDLIBS` and `LDFLAGS` into account in the linker command; that's most easily done with `$(LINK.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^` - or `$(LINK.cc) -o $@ $^` - see other answer.

Comment: @TobySpeight Answer corrected, but note that in addition to what I said earlier about OUTPUT_OPTION, LDLIBS is *not* included in LINK.cc because -l options need to be dead last on the command line.

Comment: TBH, when I need such a rule, I run `make --print-data-base` and copy/paste - which is what I should have done when commenting!

Comment: @TobySpeight That's a good habit to be in, and I did that to remind myself what `$(LINK.cc)` expands to.  But in this case it could lead you astray, because the default link rules have  `$(LOADLIBES)` in them, and I had to look that up in the manual to learn that it's an obsolete alternative name for `$(LDLIBS)`, preserved for backward compatibility, and *doesn't* need to be copied into new Makefiles.

Answer (score 4):

You are using a gcc command in the `main` part of your Makefile (line 9). You should replace it with: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^`

Comment: Even better, replace with `$(LINK.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $^` so that `LDLIBS` and so on Just Work without extra effort.

Comment: @TobySpeight $(OUTPUT_OPTION) shouldn't be used in link rules, because under some circumstances it expands to `; mv -f $(<F).o $@` which obviously doesn't work in a link rule.

Comment: Really - how does that happen?  It should always expand to `-o $@` AFAICT.

Comment: @TobySpeight It happens when Make thinks the compiler doesn't support `-o` with `-c`, which is very rare nowadays but not completely out of the question.  I don't remember how Make _decides_ whether the compiler supports `-o` with `-c`.

Comment: In that case, `$(LINK.cc) -o $@ $^`.  I sit corrected.